# How to check that given time slot is already exists in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I want to check the given start time and end time is between the start time and end time in SQLServer 2012.

**Case**: I have a table, its having two column start time and end time with two rows, Please see below that is my table

```
StartTime | EndTime

10:00:00  | 17:00:00 

17:30:00  | 18:30:00
```

**Case 1** :Given start time is '10:05:00' and end time is '16:00:00' then it should return '10:00:00' and '17:00:00'.

**Case 2** :Given start time is '09:05:00' and end time is '16:00:00' then it should return '10:00:00' and '17:00:00'.

**Case 3** :Given start time is '09:05:00' and end time is '17:15:00' then it should return '10:00:00' and '17:00:00'.

**Case 4** :Given start time is '23:05:00' and end time is '17:15:00' then it should return '10:00:00' and '17:00:00'.

**Case 5** :Given start time is '10:05:00' and end time is '17:15:00' then it should return '10:00:00' and '17:00:00'.

**Case 6** :Given start time is '17:00:00' and end time is '17:30:00' then it should not return anything.

Comment: Why don't you simply get the dates "as-is" from the db and then do the quantizing in your C# code?

Comment: Show us what you've attempted

Comment: I can't get you clearly. @Robert

Comment: Select Count(*) from table_name where 
(((StartTime between '23:05:00' AND '17:00:00') OR (ENDTime between '23:05:00' AND '17:00:00'))OR
(('23:05:00' between StartTime  AND ENDTime) OR ('17:00:00' between StartTime  AND ENDTime))
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to return the records that overlap the time period described by the parameters, right? 
Well, here is one way to do this:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as Table
(
    StartTime time,
    EndTime time
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('10:00:00', '17:00:00'),
('17:30:00', '18:30:00')
```

Declare and populate query variables:

```
DECLARE @StartTime time, @EndTime time

SELECT  @StartTime = '23:05:00', 
        @EndTime = '17:00:00'
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T 
WHERE 
(
    StartTime < @EndTime
    AND EndTime > CASE WHEN @StartTime > @EndTime THEN '00:00:00' ELSE @StartTime END
)
OR
(
    -- both periods must overlap since they both include '00:00:00'     
    @StartTime > @EndTime
    AND StartTime > EndTime
)
OR
(
    @StartTime < @EndTime
    AND StartTime > EndTime
    AND EndTime > @StartTime        
)
```

Result:

```
StartTime   EndTime
10:00:00    17:00:00
```

Note: I've taken in consideration that the time period might include two different days.

Comment: All cases works fine except Case 6. when executing case 6 it should not return anything since that slot is free. Can you help me to achieve this solutions please?

Comment: What does this mean "Please save us this step in your future questions"?

Comment: Meaning that in your future questions you should provide the sample data as DDL + DML statements, so that anyone that wants to answer the question can easily copy it to his own environment and work with it.

Comment: I will follow your suggestion

Comment: Error in above Query

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Consider If table have start time and end time respectively '23:00:00' and '17:00:00' . When I check the time range '10:00:00' - '16:00:00', it should return '23:00:00' - '17:00:00' since the given time range within this time slot.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in the last condition. Used `<` instead of `>`. Please check the new edit.

Comment: Now its working perfectly as i expected...You made my day. Thanks once again.

Comment: Again, glad to help :-)